# why my sound file in .wav format has low quality?

Tags: wireshark, pcm, wav

I work with wireshark for sniffing udp data. my data has dmr header. my data has 8 khz sampling rate and is 8 bit/sample. I save data to .wav file with PCM 16 bit but sound has low quality. how can i do for this?

Comment: If you have a bitdepth from 8 bit/sample that won't change if you save it as a file with 16 bit depth. You can't bring data back, that isn't there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

changing 8 bit to 16 bit PCM  do NOT affect sound quality.when saving sound in 16bit You just add some zero to data and make file bigger in size.
also consider the header you put for your file,it can affect sound too
to better quality you can increase sampling at least to 16KHz or increase 8 bit to 16
if you do both(16bit,16KHz), you can have good quality

Comment: Given that the data has been extracted from a UDP stream using wireshark, increasing sampling rate or bit-depth is not an option

Comment: I just want to mention that changing 8 bit to 16 bits doesn't change the quality.